Can't close margin postion with Binance API
Here example of closing position on isolated margin account but it's no working. Please help to CLOSE opened margin positions and repay margin loan. Can't find correct example of closing margin(no futures) postion on official binance-api docs. Here is full code bellow. Try to provide examples.
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
from colorama import Fore, init
from decimal import Decimal
import time

# Инициализация Colorama
init(autoreset=True)

# Ваши API-ключи
api_key = "Ваш_API_KEY"
api_secret = "Ваш_API_SECRET"

# Создание клиента Binance
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)


def get_symbol_filters(symbol):
    """Получает фильтры торговой пары."""
    try:
        symbol_info = client.get_symbol_info(symbol)
        filters = {f['filterType']: f for f in symbol_info['filters']}
        return filters
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка получения фильтров для {symbol}: {e}")
        return {}


def round_quantity(quantity, step_size):
    """Округляет количество до допустимого значения (LOT_SIZE)."""
    step_size = Decimal(step_size)
    return (Decimal(quantity) // step_size) * step_size


def get_open_position(symbol):
    """Получает данные о текущей позиции."""
    try:
        margin_account = client.get_isolated_margin_account()
        for asset in margin_account['assets']:
            if asset['symbol'] == symbol:
                base_asset = asset['baseAsset']
                quote_asset = asset['quoteAsset']
                return {
                    "base_free": Decimal(base_asset['free']),
                    "base_borrowed": Decimal(base_asset['borrowed']),
                    "quote_free": Decimal(quote_asset['free']),
                    "quote_borrowed": Decimal(quote_asset['borrowed']),
                    "base_asset": base_asset['asset'],
                    "quote_asset": quote_asset['asset']
                }
        print(Fore.YELLOW + f"⚠️ Позиция для {symbol} не найдена.")
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка получения позиций: {e}")
        return None


def close_margin_position(symbol, side, quantity):
    """Закрывает маржинальную позицию (LONG/SHORT)."""
    try:
        side_type = SIDE_SELL if side == "LONG" else SIDE_BUY
        filters = get_symbol_filters(symbol)
        lot_size_filter = filters.get('LOT_SIZE', {})
        min_qty = Decimal(lot_size_filter.get('minQty', '0'))
        step_size = Decimal(lot_size_filter.get('stepSize', '1'))

        quantity = round_quantity(quantity, step_size)

        if quantity < min_qty:
            print(Fore.YELLOW + f"ℹ️ Количество {quantity} меньше минимального LOT_SIZE ({min_qty}). Пропуск.")
            return False

        print(Fore.YELLOW + f"Попытка закрыть {side} позицию ({quantity} {symbol})...")
        client.create_margin_order(
            symbol=symbol,
            side=side_type,
            type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
            quantity=float(quantity),
            isIsolated='TRUE'
        )
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"✅ Успешно закрыта {side} позиция для {symbol}.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка при закрытии {side} позиции: {e}")
        return False


def repay_margin_loan(symbol, asset, amount):
    """Возвращает заемные средства."""
    try:
        repay_amount = Decimal(amount)
        available_balance = Decimal(client.get_asset_balance(asset)['free'])

        if repay_amount > available_balance:
            print(Fore.YELLOW + f"⚠️ Недостаточно средств для возврата {amount} {asset}. Доступно: {available_balance}.")
            repay_amount = available_balance

        if repay_amount == 0:
            print(Fore.YELLOW + f"⚠️ Невозможно вернуть {asset}, баланс равен нулю.")
            return False

        print(Fore.YELLOW + f"Возврат {repay_amount} {asset} для {symbol}...")
        client.repay_margin_loan(
            asset=asset,
            amount=str(repay_amount),
            symbol=symbol,
            isIsolated='TRUE'
        )
        print(Fore.GREEN + f"✅ Успешно возвращено {repay_amount} {asset}.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка при возврате {asset}: {e}")
        return False


def close_and_repay(symbol):
    """Закрывает позицию и возвращает заемные средства."""
    try:
        position = get_open_position(symbol)
        if not position:
            return

        base_free = position['base_free']
        base_borrowed = position['base_borrowed']
        quote_free = position['quote_free']
        quote_borrowed = position['quote_borrowed']

        # Закрытие LONG
        if base_free > 0:
            while base_free > 0:
                if close_margin_position(symbol, "LONG", base_free):
                    time.sleep(3)
                    base_free = get_open_position(symbol)['base_free']

        # Закрытие SHORT
        if quote_borrowed > 0:
            while quote_borrowed > 0:
                if close_margin_position(symbol, "SHORT", quote_borrowed):
                    time.sleep(3)
                    quote_borrowed = get_open_position(symbol)['quote_borrowed']

        # Возврат долгов
        if base_borrowed > 0:
            while base_borrowed > 0:
                repay_margin_loan(symbol, position['base_asset'], base_borrowed)
                time.sleep(3)
                base_borrowed = get_open_position(symbol)['base_borrowed']

        if quote_borrowed > 0:
            while quote_borrowed > 0:
                repay_margin_loan(symbol, position['quote_asset'], quote_borrowed)
                time.sleep(3)
                quote_borrowed = get_open_position(symbol)['quote_borrowed']

        print(Fore.GREEN + f"✅ Все операции по {symbol} завершены.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка при обработке {symbol}: {e}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print(Fore.YELLOW + "Инициализация Binance API...")
        client.ping()
        print(Fore.GREEN + "✅ Успешное подключение!")
        close_and_repay("XRPUSDT")
    except Exception as e:
        print(Fore.RED + f"❌ Ошибка подключения к Binance API: {e}")

Here example of closing position on isolated margin account but it's no working. Please help to CLOSE opened margin positions and repay margin loan. Can't find correct example of closing margin(no futures) postion on official binance-api docs. Here is full code bellow. Try to provide examples.
